# In Django, how can i pass information to the server without showing in the link?

Tags: python, django, server

i know we can pass information to the function that calls the template that way:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("domain/<str:u>/",views.pd)
]
```

in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def rt(req,u):
    print(u)
    return render(req,'teste.html')
```

But how can we do this without showing the information in the link? For exemple, without 'http://localhost:8000/route/aaa/' in the link for passing the 'aaa' string

Comment: you could use a parameter wrapped in a html template tag ( {{ variable }} ) to store the data on the client side and pass it to the view using request.POST.get[variable] e.g.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: send information in payload. You can use any HTTP methods to send requests, but conventionally POST is widely used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case, `URL` when sending post parameters doesnt contain anything related to parameters in the `URL`. To achieve that you would follow a similar approach as below.

For the html elements:

```
<input type='text' name='num' value=5 />
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^register/$', 'register', name='urlname')
```

The corresponding view will be:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        request.POST['num']  # returns 5
    return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

See this article [here](https://django.cowhite.com/blog/working-with-url-get-post-parameters-in-django/) for a detailed rundown of how you can solve this problem.